# How to address a function inside an if condition using C# in unity 3D

Tags: unity, c#

I am new to game development and have very limited idea of C# syntax. I was watching unity 3D tutorials of UI and thought of using [ModalPanel.cs and TestModalWindow.cs](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/live-training-archive/modal-window-pt2)
In a quiz game where 3 choices are there of a question and total 5 questions are there

Now suppose in

```
public void TestNYCI ()
{
   modalPanel.Choice(
         " string? ", 
         icon, 
         TestYesFunction, 
         TestNoFunction, 
         TestCancelFunction);

   // Here I want to use an if loop
   // if ( condition)
   // where condition means choosing of a function among 
   // TestYesFunction, TestNoFunction, TestCancelFunction

   //Statements 

   // If suppose TestYesFunction is true I want 
   // to increment the count and write it as score 
}
```

And will repeat the process in rest of the 5 functions.

Can someone please provide a suitable syntax to address the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it should be understood that what happens after the modalPanel.Choice() call will not be affected by the choice made in modalPanel.Choice(). The line modalPanel.Choice() line will be run showing the panel although the panel is showing the execution of the TestNYCI() method does not stop. So any if statement dependent on the users choice in the panel would not be gotten. This is where the 3 UnityActions come in. Each one tells the system how to react to its respective button press.

Next, it should be noted that the three UnityActions are already conditional branches. So using you example the TestYesFunction would have some way of incrementing the score. This should be set up before you call the modalPanel.Choice() method. Something like:

```
void TestNYCI(Question question) 
{
    var answerChosen = new UnityAction[3];
    for(i=0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        answerChosen[i] = () => { 
            var answerIndex = i; 
            // check is answer i is correct and score accordingly
        };
// Alternatively
        if(/* check is answer i is correct */) 
        {
            answerChosen[i] = HandleCorrectAnswer;
        }
        else
        {
            answerChosen[i] = HandleWrongAnswer;
         }
    }

    modalPanel.Choice(question.Text,
        icon,
        answerChosen[0],
        answerChosen[1],
        answerChosen[2]);
}
```

It is important that if you do it the first way that you create a variable inside the lambda to store the index for each iteration because you will get an error either during compilation or and IndexOutOfRangeException because all 3 answerChosen items will behave as if i = 3